# Quitar los bordes cuando este activo el input

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando quitar los bordes del `input` cuando este **focuseado** o activo, pero no funciona de ninguna manera estoy usando bootstrap y sass, pero de ninguna forma esta funcionando aqui muestro lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseao quitar el borde amarillo-rojo-verde que aparece ahi cuando se le de **click** para escribir

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="form-group mx-auto">
             <input type="email" class="form-control-lg border-0" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
       </div>

 </div>
```

> Estilos

```
.form-control-lg {
            background: $main-color-l;
            border-bottom: 2px solid $shadow-green !important;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 10px;

            &:focus {
                border: none;
            }

            &:active {
                border: none;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Salvo que tengas los estilos de bootstrap después de los que deseas aplicar de manera personalizada; es decir:

El orden de tus códigos CSS debería estar así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="misestilos.css">
```

> Para que de este modo si tienes tú código organizado así, los últimos  en aplicarse sean los estilos personalizados

Ahora con CSS tendrías un input así:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control-lg border-0" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
```

Posterior con CSS  modificamos su apariencia de este modo:

```
.form-control-lg{
      border: 1px solid red;
      outline: none;
}
```

- Usamos la *pseudoclase* `:focus` para identificar cuando la caja de texto se le ha dado click y esta disponible para escritura
- Con `outline: none;` quitamos el borde por defecto que se coloca cuando ponemos el cursor del mouse
- Con `border: 1px solid red;` solo estamos poniendo un color distinto que haga que se note el cambio

**Ejemplo completo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        .form-control-lg{
          border: solid 1px blue;
        }
        .form-control-lg:focus{
          border: 1px solid red;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control-lg">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias, muy buena respuesta, no tenia conocimiento del outline