# ¿Quitar rebode de puntos en un botón?

Tags: html, css, botón

Tengo un problema que no he conseguido resolver de ninguna forma, ni con las respuestas que he encontrado por aquí.
Me gustaría saber como se quitar el recuadro de puntos que sale en firefox cuando le das a un botón. En chrome es la misma propiedad, solo que en vez de ser un recuadro de punto es una línea de color azul.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El reborde de punto es ese que se ve en la imagen. Repido que solo sale cuando le clicas al botón. y es molestisimo que salga.

El boton lo tengo puesto así en el html (hay mas botones pero son todos igual a este):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" name="otros" id="cinco" value="5" onclick="mouseEvents(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

El codigo CSS sería el siguente:

```
input[type="button"]:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

input[name="otros"]{
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    color: lightgrey;
    width: 5em;
    height: 3em;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}

input[name="otros"]:hover{
background-color: grey;
transition: all 0.5s;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con la propiedad `outline` que se menciona en esta respuesta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/quitar-los-bordes-cuando-este-activo-el-input/291436#291436 por cierto para poderte ayudar mejor sería ideal que agregues tu código y de ese modo podamos reproducir el problema que expones

Comment: El boton no tiene ninguna propiedad en especial, solo es un botón al que le he cambiado los colores. Efectivamente he probado el outline, pero no me funciona.
Tengo entendido que es con focus, pero no me funciona aun así.

Comment: Por favor aún asi considera añadir tu código, se que tal vez es muy obvio pero ayudará a cumplir con los lineamientos de [ask]

Comment: Aquí esta otro ejemplo, que quizás te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031517/cross-browser-solution-to-remove-browser-default-focus-styles

Comment: He añadido ya el código correspondiente a ese botón, espero que ayude un poco.
Lo del outline = 0 es como lo tengo ahora.

Comment: Pues con las propiedades de `outline` que has añadido he reproducido tu ejemplo y no me aparece ese efecto de orilla azul que mencionas (estoy en Chrome)

Comment: He probado y efectivamente en chrome no surge el inconveniente del outline, pero en firefox sigue saliendo el recuadro de puntitos de la imagen. No tengo ni idea de por qué.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que tengas que ser un poco más agresivo y decirle algo así añadiéndole por ejemplo una clase si quieres que solo se le aplique a ese:

```
 .ClaseQueTuQuieras:hover, .ClaseQueTuQuieras:focus, .ClaseQueTuQuieras:active {border: none ! important, outline:0 ! important }
```

Si es para todo los inputs, pues lógicamente cambias el 'ClaseQueTuQuieras' por 'input'. que esto pueda servirte.

Comment: No no, no es eso, también lo probé, por alguna razon el :focus en firefox no me funciona como en chrome. Igual es que estoy intentando hacer algo imposible.