# ¿Como le quito borde cuando seleccion input=text?

Tags: html, css, css3

En un formulario que estoy haciendo cuando selecciono el "input type text" le pone un marco raro alrededor, ¿como le quito o como lo adapto a el border radius?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.campos_de_formulario{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline:none;
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: Agrega ` !important` a tus reglas css y me cuentas que tal

Comment: No es eso, solo quiero quitarle es borde negro con blanco que pasa al seleccionar

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero comparta ejemplo verificable; una imagen sirve para dar una idea como esta, pero solo pones una parte del CSS que no se sabe si realmente es allí donde se deba realizar el cambio; así mismo, espero su "No es eso..." ojala sea por que verifico realmente *no es eso*.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Quitar los bordes cuando este activo el input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/quitar-los-bordes-cuando-este-activo-el-input)

Comment: Important es una mala práctica y su uso debería ser mínimo o nulo

Comment: @BetaM Gracias por el alcance, aún así es bastante funcional cuando se requiere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando das clic en el input lo que se muestra no es un borde es un contorno.
El código que agregas no creo que sea el que estas implementando pues no veo el border-radius que le estas asignando ni el fondo. Revisa que el nombre de tu clase sea la misma en HTML y CSS. Con los siguientes estilos tu input debe quedar

```
.campos_de_formulario{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border-radius: 12px;  
  outline: none; 
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando escribes en un input se produce un evento focus, lo que deberías hacer es señalar los estilos para ese input con ese evento activado.

```
input :focus{
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el outline:none; ya se deberia de quitar, asegurate de colocar esa propiedad en la clase de tu input.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```css
* {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .container {

        height: 500px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .container input {
        background-color: #BDBDBD;
        width: 500px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 30px;
    

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>



<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```