# ¿Cómo sacar border de select e inputs?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy buscando la manera de poder sacar unos bordes de unos select y un input que no quiero que tengan. He buscado en internet pero no encuentro la solución. ¿Alguien sabe?

Son estos bordes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos bordes azules son los que quiero sacar. ¿Alguien sabe?

Código de los inputs y selects:

```
<label for="Fecha">
  <input class="form-control mr-3 botones_inicio mb-3" type="date" name="Fecha" id="fecha" value="<?= (isset($_POST['Fecha']) ? $_POST['Fecha'] : date("Y-m-d")); ?>">
</label>

<label for="Sucursal">
  <select class="form-select botones_inicio mb-3" name="Sucursal_turno" id="Sucursal_turno" required>
    <option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']; ?></option>
  </select>
</label>

<label for="profesional">
  <select class="form-select botones_inicio mb-3" name="Usuario_truno" id="Usuario_truno" required>
    <?php foreach ($profesional_pro as $dato3) {
      if (isset($_POST["Usuario_truno"]) && $_POST["Usuario_truno"] == $dato3->NOMBRE_PROFESIONAL)
        echo '<option value="' . $dato3->NOMBRE_PROFESIONAL . '" selected>' . $dato3->NOMBRE_PROFESIONAL, " ", $dato3->APELLIDO_PROFESIONAL . ' </option>';
      else
        echo '<option value="' . $dato3->NOMBRE_PROFESIONAL . '">' . $dato3->NOMBRE_PROFESIONAL, " ", $dato3->APELLIDO_PROFESIONAL . ' </option>';
    ?>

    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: Buen día, te invito a repasar la sección de [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tal como está escrita tu pregunta no se entiende lo que deseas hacer. Por favor añade el código que tienes hasta ahora para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Quitar los bordes cuando este activo el input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/quitar-los-bordes-cuando-este-activo-el-input)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Revisando Boostrap con el inspector de chrome, esos bordes azules son producto de

```
.form-select:focus {
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 25%);
}
```

Asi que para volarlos deberias reescribir ese selector, para `.form-select` o para cualquier caja que te presente ese borde.

```
.form-select:focus {
    border-color: #dee2e6;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Si ya lo agrege y sigue mostrando esos bordes

Comment: Será que el plugin que usas tiene estilos que sobre-escriben los tuyos? Probaste con un ``outline: none !important;``?

Comment: si bro le agregue el !important y aun sigue mostrandose

Comment: @FdeFacundo ahi revisé Boostrap con el inspector y tenés razón, ese borde está producido por un box-shadow, no por un outline. Modifiqué la respuesta, espero que ahí sirva. En el inspector no fue necesario ponerle !important pero no sé si en tu caso harán falta.

Comment: exactamente mi querido Agustin, muchas gracias