# No puedo sacar sombra o borde del input en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, input, shadow

Tengo un problema con los estilos de un input de bootstrap, no puede remover la sombra o el borde que tiene al estar activo. Tiene esa sombra o borde y no puedo sacarla.
Dejo el código de bootstrap del input, gracias.

[image: Borde azul]

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="form-control">
```

Comment: Prueba a poner `box-shadow: none` y `outline: none`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Quitar los bordes cuando este activo el input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/quitar-los-bordes-cuando-este-activo-el-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas darle estilos al `<input>` cuando el elemento tiene el foco. Para eso puedes usar la pseudo-clase `:focus` para pisar los estilos que Boostrap tiene definidos.

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

/** Para evitar el sombreado cuando el input tiene el foco **/
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="form-control">
```