# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el outline azul que viene por defecto en los botones (class="btn") de bootstrap cuando le doy click?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, scss

Estoy haciendo un block con varias secciones en bootstrap y Sass, todas tienen inputs a los que les he modificado los estilos cuando están en :active y :focus. en ambos eventos me aplica perfectamente los estilos, pero siempre al darle click aparece un outline azul, que por defecto viene en la clase btn de bootstrap. he intentado eliminarlo de varias formas desde Sass o bootstrap y al darle click siempre aparece

Acá   el index.html y su clase en bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proyecto</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="Text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body >

    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <div class="container ">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
               
                <span class="h6 color-light"> <strong>Diego</strong> Calles</span>
            </a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon" data-bs- 
            toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu-desplegable" 
                    aria-expanded="false"  aria-controls="menu-desplegable" aria-label="Desplegar menu principal">
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="menu-desplegable">
                <ul class="navbar-nav color ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">¿Quién soy?</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#proyecto" class="nav-link">Proyectos</a></li>
                    

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- sección ¿Quién soy? -->

    <section class="quien-soy py-4 mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <img src="./images/desarrollador.svg" alt="soy el desarrollador" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12  col-md-6 text-center">
                    <!-- clase display-3 para incrementar el size del texto  y el fw-bold para ponerla en negrita-->
                    <h2 class="display-3 fw-bold text-primary">¿Quién soy? </h2>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus repudiandae voluptatem aliquam quod sit alias
                        omnis! Totam reprehenderit ducimus sapiente dolor,
                        cum, asperiores libero labore, error dolorem saepe doloribus voluptas.
                    </p>
                    <!-- btn-lg para hacerlo mas grnde -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Leer más</a>
                </div>
               
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- sección filosofía -->

    <section class="filosofia py-4 bg-primary text-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center " >
                    <img src="./images/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class=" border rounded-circle img-fluid w-25  mb-3 mb-4 bg-white">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <p class="h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium dolor in accusamus dolorum accusantium et?
                       Aspernatur veritatis quia blanditiis deserunt sunt atque error a tenetur! Provident in dolorem quisquam obcaecati.
                    </p>
                    <p class="h5 fst-italic">-Diego Calles</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- seccion Mis Proyectos -->
                    
    <section class="mis-proyectos py-4">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center display-3 fw-bold my-3 pb-4">Mis Proyectos</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- img  p-1 -->
                
                <article class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-2 ">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid h-100" src="./images/proyecto1.png" alt="proyecto 1">
                        <div class="card-body text-md-center">
                            <h5 class="card-title" id="proyecto">Proyecto 1</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ver proyecto</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- img  p-2 -->

                <article class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-2 ">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid h-100" src="./images/proyecto2.png" alt="proyecto 2">
                        <div class="card-body text-md-center">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Proyecto 2</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ver proyecto</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- img  p-3 -->

                <article class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-2 ">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid h-100" src="./images/proyecto3.png" alt="proyecto 3">
                        <div class="card-body text-md-center">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Proyecto 3</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-focus-shadow">Ver proyecto</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <!-- img  p-4 -->

                <article class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-2 ">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid h-100" src="./images/proyecto4.png" alt="proyecto 4">
                        <div class="card-body text-md-center">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Proyecto 4</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ver proyecto</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            
    </section>
       
    <!-- footer -->
    <footer class="bg-dark">
        <div class="text-center text-white  ">
            <p class="py-3">Copyright © 2022 | Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
        </div>

    </footer>

     <!-- Archivos bootstrap.js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

acá el código en Sass

```
$primary:#ff401c;

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus{
   background-color:darken($primary,10)!important;
   border-color:darken($primary,10) !important;
   
}

.btn-primary:active{
   background-color:darken($primary,20)!important;
   border-color:darken($primary,20) !important;
   
   
  
}
```

he intentado con estos atributos en Sass, sin el resultado esperado

```
.btn-primary:active{
  background-color:darken($primary,20)!important;
  border-color:darken($primary,20) !important;
  outline-style:hidden !important;
  outline:none !important;
}
    
   
.btn-primary:active{
  background-color:darken($primary,20)!important;
  border-color:darken($primary,20) !important;
  outline-style:none !important;
  outline:none !important; 
}
```

Comment: ```
box-shadow:none !important; :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Quitar los bordes cuando este activo el input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291434/quitar-los-bordes-cuando-este-activo-el-input). Adicional, este borde es propio del navegador, no del framework ni de tu CSS. Puedes quitarlo, pero genera problemas de accesibilidad.